# Load angularjs timer plus 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the [angularjs timer](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker). It loads the current system time. But i want to load plus 15 mintues from current system time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the Date 15 Minutes (in Milliseconds) in the furture:

```
var minInFuture = 1000*60*15;

var d = new Date();
var newDate = new Date(d.getTime()+minInFuture);

$scope.mytime = newDate;
```

The model *mytime* is passed to angularjs's date compontent.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
$scope.update = function() {
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()+15);
$scope.mytime = d;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a filter, like this.

```
.filter('addTime', function(){
  return function(current_date, add_minutes){
    return (current_date.getTime() + 1000*60*add_minutes);
  }
});
```

Then in html file:

```
{{mytime | addTime:add_minutes | date:'shortTime' }}
```

where add_minutes is a variable defined in your controller(as minutes). Now you can use this filter anywhere that you like, always aim for DRY.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/4aY8NRSVLjqlrAqcA3YL?p=preview